# Error code: Out of Memory - How to allocate more memory to Google Chrome - 64 GB ram available

Tags: google-chrome, memory

I have searched thoroughly and couldn't find any answer

I am using Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have got 64 GB ram and currently more than 30GB is free as seen below

[image]

And yet I am getting the error below which is very annoying

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly related from [so]: [Max memory usage of a chrome process (tab) & how do I increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491022/max-memory-usage-of-a-chrome-process-tab-how-do-i-increase-it)

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416284 also suggests that there is a 4GB limit per tab.

Comment: Why do you need Chrome to use more memory? Why do you think this is just a matter of "forcing" it to use more memory? What is the webpage or tab that is causing this error? How do you provoke this error? What do you see in the Chrome Task Manager **Tools > Task Manager** ?

Comment: @Mokubai error happened on deviantart. I want it to use more ram so it wont crash as seen in picture so simple. 4gb per tab limit this could be reason sadly :( any working method on the links above? they all looks outdated

Comment: If you are hitting that big a limit then exactly what you are doing there is relevant. I don't feel like this is something you should be hitting in "normal" use of *any* website... I can't provoke Firefox to use a significant amount of RAM **at all** even when scrolling down the front page for a long way (always <1GB). In Edge I can browse an insane distance down the page to gobble up 3+GB and then scrolling up and down a few times eats even more RAM but I haven't seen a 4GB limit there. Seems Chrome/Chromium memory management is just kinda awful. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: @Mokubai i havent tried with other browsers. i am scrolling down with thousands of images perhaps 10ks.

Comment: @Mokubai currently google chrome is using 5gb according to task manager. i have so many tabs open for my business. i added screenshot to the first message

Comment: Yeah, in Edge I seemingly get to a "end of page" thing some huge number of page-downs and it uses around 4.2GB of RAM but no error or crash. Firefox seems to happily limit RAM use and only use memory on what it's actually showing you at the time while Edge buffers *everything* with occasional garbage cleanups clawing back a 100MB here and there. Do you have any addons or ad-blockers that might be changing behaviours? If so try disabling all addons and seeing if it still happens

Comment: Just to confirm. you have not disabled your virtual memory have you?

Comment: @Ramhound virtual memory is enabled.

Comment: @Mokubai this is a query that i go : https://www.deviantart.com/search?q=fakemon

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG In Edge I just hit "End of Results" at 2.5GB of RAM used by a single tab with no crash.

Comment: Are you allowing the system to manage the size or is it a fixed amount? I can scroll the page on my iPhone without an issue (Safari and Chrome). I was also able to view it on my PC with Edge, which has 200 tabs open, without a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound you are only considering single tab. Also that query has over 200k results are you sure you have loaded all? Moreover, I have so many tabs open. Also I am opening new tabs from the results and doing extra things. Nevertheless my chrome crashes and I have posted crash screenshot and the crash reason is not enough memory

Comment: Have you tried disabling adblock and any other addons as I suggested? That would at least rule it/them out.

Answer (score 4):

As has been suggested by others, you should remove all extraneous plugins etc., whether you believe them to be guiltless or not.

1. There is a 16G limit per tab in Chrome and Edge. There is nothing you can do about this -- there is no magic solution -- until the developers decide to increase the limit. If you don't believe me, you can prove it to yourself by writing a small piece of javascript to allocate memory until you run out. Note that you should allocate large fixed arrays for this, otherwise you may hit the "X" limit as described below well before you hit the 16G limit.
2. You may not be running into an "actual" limitation of memory at all.  Rather, you could be running out of "objects X" as described below, or you could be running out of string space, both of which can be reported by the browser as "out of memory" conditions even when you are actually using much less memory than 16G.
3. Try opening your page in Firefox which has higher limits on X and can allocate up to 32G per tab (32G was proven via testing; I do not know if it can handle more). If the page opens in Firefox, you can examine the FF memory footprint, and if it is using less than 16G, then your problem in Chrome is obviously "X".

If your problem is "X", then you must reduce array/object usage (or string usage) in your app. There are some ideas on how to do this below.

Comment: Ty for answer but still I would like to get a solution. I have ram so the chrome should not crash due to not enough memory error

Comment: It is also possible that addons can be adding or modifying elements in a way that causes memory to bloat or to exhaust other objects in unexpected ways. That I cannot replicate the error in another Chromium based browser (Edge) suggests that this is either specific to Chrome or possibly addons.

Comment: @Mokubai i only have adblock plus as addon

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG then disable it and try again. Apparently Adblock might end up doing that at times: https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=74688 and https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000087874-adblock-is-using-lots-of-memory FWIW, I use uBlock which claims to use less memory and cycles than others.